# programme not running in background

Tags: android

i have an app which reads out the messages as it is received. The pgm seems to be working fine when i launch it or even when i press the back button on the emulator, however when i start another app in the same emulator and then if a message is received then i can see the message as Toast but am unable to receive any sound, so how do i correct that?

**TextSpeaker **

```
package com.example.TextSpeaker;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
 import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

// the following programme converts the text to speech 

public class TextSpeaker extends Activity  implements OnInitListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
public static TextToSpeech mtts;
public Button button,stop_button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    stop_button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop_button);

    Intent myintent = new Intent();
    myintent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(myintent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
    //edit text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
 }

    public void buttonClickListener(View src){
     switch(src.getId())
     {
     case(R.id.button):
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The service has been started\n Every new message will now be read out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          //Intent serviceintent = new Intent(this,SpeakerService.class);
          //serviceintent.setAction(".SpeakerService");
          //startService(new Intent(this,SpeakerService.class));
         // startService(serviceintent);
          break;
     case(R.id.stop_button):
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The service has been stopped\n ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         mtts.stop(); 
      //stopService(new Intent(this,SpeakerService.class));
      break;
     }
    }



    protected void onActivityResult(int requestcode,int resultcode,Intent data)
    {
     if(requestcode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE)
     {
      if(resultcode==TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS)
      {
       // success so create the TTS engine
       Log.v("TextSpeaker","Pico is installed in the system");
       mtts = new TextToSpeech(this,this);
       mtts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);

      }
      else
      {
       //install the Engine
       Intent install = new Intent();
       install.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
       startActivity(install);
      }
     }

    }
    public void onDestroy(Bundle savedInstanceStatBundle)
    { 
     //mtts.shutdown();
    }

    //public void onPause()
    //{ 
    // super.onPause();
    // // if our app has no focus
    // if(mtts!=null)
    //  mtts.stop();
   // }
  @Override
  public void onInit(int status) {
   if(status==TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
   button.setEnabled(true);


      }       
   }
```

**Receiver**

```
package com.example.TextSpeaker;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage; // supports both gsm and cdma
import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.Toast;



public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{


public static String str="";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
Log.d("Receiver","Message received successfully");

SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

if(bundle!=null)
 {
// retrive the sms received

 Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
 msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
 for(int i=0;i<msgs.length;i++)
  {
 str="";
 msgs[i]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
 str+="Message From "+msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress()+".";
 str+="The message is "+msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
 TextSpeaker.mtts.speak(Receiver.str, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
 }
 Toast.makeText(context,str,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



  }
 }
 }
```

Comment: i cheked the logcat ,and found that when i start a new app, then i get  the Toast message but for the speech i get "null synthesis-can't speak" .. could someone please explain why is it so ?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because the speech synthesis library hasn't been installed by default on your Android device. Try visiting the android market and installing the [Speech Synthesis Language Pack](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.svox.langpack.installer) - then try again.

Not all devices have it installed by default, even some of the very new ones.